# Como Exportar uma tabela HTML para PDF e EXCEL

Tags: javascript, java, html, pdf

Bom dia pessoal, alguem tem como me dar uma ajuda referente a exportar uma tabela HTML para PDF e EXCEL, é melhor eu fazer isso no javascript(front end) ou no java (backend) qualquer dica ajuda! valeu.

Comment: Referente a resposta do Otácio Barbosa, seu script não funciona para tabela com mais de 30 mil registros, da falha no download do arquivo, alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### É melhor eu fazer isso no javascript(front end) ou no (backend)?

É melhor fazer isso no back-end por questões de segurança. Uma página `HTML` pode ser manipulada, e com isso ter seus dados manipulados. Se você fizer isso no back-end, você retorna os valores verdadeiros para o arquivo que será exportado, seja em qual for o formato de saída.

---

Dito isso, irei postar uma forma simples de fazer isso utilizando [jQuery.](https://jquery.com/)

```
    <input type="button" id="btnExport" value=" Export Table data into Excel " />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="dvData">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Column One</th>
                <th>Column Two</th>
                <th>Column Three</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row1 Col1</td>
                <td>row1 Col2</td>
                <td>row1 Col3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row2 Col1</td>
                <td>row2 Col2</td>
                <td>row2 Col3</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>

 <script>
    $("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
        window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData').html());
        e.preventDefault();
    });
  </script>
```

Veja um exemplo completo [neste Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/jWAJ7/)(Fonte no link).

Se quiser um exemplo completo em JavaScript, [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24081343/4843158) pode lhe ajudar.

Existe algumas bibliotecas que fazer isso também, como a [ExcellentExport.js](https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport).

---

Já em java, você pode fazer da seguinte forma, [conforme essa resposta.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21278574/4843158)

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet personSheet = wb.createSheet("PersonList");
Row headerRow = personSheet.createRow(0);
Cell nameHeaderCell = headerRow.createCell(0);
Cell addressHeaderCell = headerRow.createCell(1);

String sql = "select name, address from person_table";
PrepareStatement ps =  connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();    

int row = 1;
while(resultSet.next()) {
    String name = resultSet.getString("name");
    String address = resultSet.getString("address");

    Row dataRow = personSheet.createRow(row);

    Cell dataNameCell = dataRow.createCell(0);
    dataNameCell.setCellValue(name);

    Cell dataAddressCell = dataRow.createCell(1);
    dataAddressCell.setCellValue(address);

    row = row + 1;
}

String outputDirPath = "D:/PersonList.xls";
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outputDirPath);
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Comment: Valeu pela resposta @Randrade, exemplo muito simples funcionou perfeitamente para excel (tanto no back quanto no front), por acaso voce tambem não tem um codigo para exportar p/ PDF ><?

Comment: "Uma página HTML pode ser manipulada, e com isso ter seus dados manipulados.". Qualquer um pode duplicar o arquivo e modificar se quiser, Se for ESTRITAMENTE NECESSÁRIO deixar a tabela segura pelo back-end vai precisar de um sistema de autenticação dessas tabelas com [assinaturas Hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_cryptography). Simplesmete gerar a tabela no back-end só vai gerar processos desnecessários, Imagina se um usuário exporta um relatório de 500mil linhas? Vai congestionar o servidor inteiro, por isso é melhor fazer no front-end e deixar o cliente tratar do processamento.

Answer (score 5):

Bom dia,
 Você pode estar usando 2 plugins de jquery,segue o exemplo:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title>Export HTML table to Excel Format With Jquery- WSnippets.com</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Export HTML table to Excel Format With Jquery- WSnippets.com" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />    
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="test">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h2>WSnippets.com - Export HTML table to Excel Format With Jquery</h2>
             <div id="dv">
                <table id="tblExport" style="border:1px solid black; ">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Username</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style='background-color:red;'>1</td>
                            <td>Mark</td>
                            <td>Otto</td>
                            <td>@mdo</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>Jacob</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                            <td>@fat</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>Larry</td>
                            <td>the Bird</td>
                            <td>@twitter</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button id="btnExport">Export to excel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.btechco.excelexport.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.base64.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnExport").click(function () {
            $("#tblExport").btechco_excelexport({
                containerid: "tblExport"
               , datatype: $datatype.Table
               , filename: 'sample'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Segue um tutorial do autor original e na página contem os arquivos para download.

http://codigosimples.net/2014/11/27/exportar-html-para-excel-com-jquery/

Comment: Olá @Otacio, apesar do link responder a pergunta, seria bom você trazer o código para sua resposta, vai que a internet exploda e somente esse site é afetado? :p

Comment: Quando tiver 50 pontos de reputação pode colocar esse tipo de dica como comentário na pergunta. A intenção do site é ser uma biblioteca de soluções, não de links. E as respostas que ganham pontos são as que mostram a solução, as deste tipo aqui são sinalizadas para ser deletadas...

Comment: Valeu pela resposta @Otacio Barbosa, funcionou certinho para excel, por acaso voce tambem não tem pra PDF não ?

Comment: Tem esse aqui,mais esse ainda não testei,caso teste por favor retornar se conseguiu:http://w3lessons.info/2015/07/13/export-html-table-to-excel-csv-json-pdf-png-using-jquery/

Comment: Randrade e Review - Diego F e brasfilo , resposta altera e inseria os códigos.

Comment: @Otacio Barbosa, esse esquema não funcionou pra mim por que preciso exportar pra PDF mas renderizando o CSS